# Update a column using another modified in the same query

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have a query to update two fields. The value of the first field is obtained with a subquery and the second is conditional, you can use the same subquery as field one or a different one. In the case of using the same subquery I simply assign the value of field one but it assigns its old value to me. Shouldn't I get the new value? How can I optimize this without repeating the subquery?

Example:

```
UPDATE table SET 
field1 = (SELECT count(*) FROM table2),
field2 (
    CASE WHEN condition THEN (SELECT count(*) FROM table2 WHERE field = 'foo') ELSE (SELECT count(*) FROM table2) END
);
```

My wrong solution:

```
UPDATE table SET 
field1 = (SELECT count(*) FROM table2),
field2 (
    CASE WHEN condition THEN (SELECT count(*) FROM table2 WHERE field = 'foo') ELSE field1 END
);
```

Comment: that is much to abstract, every subquery needs to return  a scalar value and we know nothing abourt, so it will work or you get an error which we also don't know

Comment: @nbk I updated my example

Comment: that is somewhat complicates, counts are notorious slow, i would write a Subquery Grouped by field and have corelated sum over the result, that i would join to the update table. so basically i subquery (there are 2 becuae you need the total sum, but if you need the tortla count often, you shoud use a seperate table to hold the total count(updates with triggers) in the lng run this is quicker then to get the total count every time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To reuse the same subquery multiple times, use a [Common Table Expression](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html).

```sql
WITH memo AS (SELECT count(*) count FROM table2)
UPDATE table SET
field1 = (SELECT count FROM memo),
field2 = CASE WHEN condition THEN (...) ELSE (SELECT count FROM memo) END
```

As far as I know there's no good way to directly reference the new value for field1 when setting field2.

Comment: This has worked correctly for me and the EXPLAIN PLAN says that the complexity is half